# Permissions granted but requests return null

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to access Microsoft Todo app using Graph API, I have added all the permissions required for the todo app but I forgot to change the status of the permission or grant it.
After I granted the permissions, I got a new refresh token and tried but I still can't access my todo app. When I tried this through graph explorer it worked, When I used the access token from graph explorer, it also worked. How can I solve this?

[image]

Update: Do I need to enable Directory sync in the Users, If yes how do I enable it?

Also the userID from graph explorer and my app don't match, The userID I got from my office 360 account doesn't match the userID from my app but matches the one from graph explorer

> API Request:

```
def getTodoLists(self):
    query = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists"
    response = requests.get(query,
                            headers={
                                "content-type": "application/json",
                                "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(self.access_token)},
                            )
    response_json = response.json()
    print(response)
    print(response_json)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using refresh token after consent is granted, you are facing the issue.

After the permissions are added and admin consent is granted, you need to **generate a new access toke**n instead of using refresh token

Using the new access token, now you be able to access Microsoft Todo app using Graph API

Comment: But won't the access token expire in 1 hour

Comment: I started over and created a new registration, this time with the permissions granted at the start itself, but even then I get the same result

Comment: Which flow are you using to generate the access token?

Comment: I am using Oauth2.0 flow

Comment: When I use the access token I got using the refresh token, I only get one value that is the default `Task` list, whereas I get three tasks list from graph explorer

Comment: Can you add the details of your API query in the question

Comment: API query of which request?

Comment: Graph explorer does not use the app registration. Instead, it uses user account through which user is logged in to graph explorer

Comment: Hmm ok what am I doing wrong in the authentication process

Comment: Go the explorer. Under modify permissions, check which permissions are added for the API request. Then add the same permissions to the app registration

Comment: I added all required permissions in the app and also decoded the access token and it contains all the required scopes

Comment: But the issue still persists

Comment: Can you please add your API request for which you are facing the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241851/discussion-between-ramaraoadapa-mt-and-rohith-nambiar).